# Useful Book for starting to programming quantative Finance

Tags: programming

Could anyone recommend me a good book for an introduction to start programming quantative finance (preferably in R)? I found a lot of different ones, but unfortunately without any reviews.

Comment: A very good one is An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation: Mathematics, Stochastics and Computation. It's in Matlab (which is close to R) and very good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents!

Simulation and Inference for Stochastic Differential Equations, with R Examples, by Stefano M.lacus

The name is a bit geeky but it is very quant 'financy'.